# Use an Excel cell like an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file and I have to count the number of "." for each cell. One cell has some characters (for example 'A01.10.10.10')
Is it possible transfer into an array the content of a single cell?

Comment: `arr(0) = myCell.Value` or did you mean `arr = Split(myCell.Value, ".")`  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Split()` for this:

```
myArray = Split(Range("A1"), ".")
```

That will "Split" `Range("A1")` contents by a period into an array.

---

You could also just go straight to the return of the `split()` function to get the ubound since the return is an array (skipping the need to `dim` the array):

```
UBound(Split(Range("A1"),"."))
```

Which would spit out `3` given your input.

Comment: The answer should be 3 in that example

Comment: Oh yes @Tom! Fixed it up so it doesn't mislead.

Comment: Also, the output of `Split` shouldn't be set. It should be `myArray = Split(Range("A1"), ".")`

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I should test this schlock before tossing it up as an answer.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Comment: @JNevill Thank you so much. Your solution works like I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need an array to do this?

You can get your answer in an Excel formula by using

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))
```

Or `VBA`

```
Sub CountDots()
    Dim str As String
    str = "A01.10.10.10"
    MsgBox Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, ".", vbNullString))
End Sub
```

No need for an array. If you are going to do something else with the string and need it in an array though then use @JNevill answer

Comment: Dammit @Tom, was about to paste that exact same formula... `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))`  :)

Comment: Damn, I hit enter on my answer with len/sub method, then saw you had an update to yours... and you added it, too lol

Answer (score 1):

You can found the "." in a single cell using a formula:

```
=Len(targetcell)-Len(Substitute(targetcell,".",""))
```

Counts the number of cells, then counts the number of cells after the "." has been replaced with "" (nothing).

You wouldn't need an array for that.